# No static method dispatchUnhandledKeyEventPre

Tags: kotlin, androidx

My app crashes whenever i press the back button or the menu button. I'm using androidx and kotlin. Below is my logcat

> 07-06 18:47:25.538 22303-22303/com.mnkafe.mnkafe E/InputEventSender:
>   Exception dispatching finished signal. 07-06 18:47:25.538
>   22303-22303/com.mnkafe.mnkafe E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in
>   MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback 07-06 18:47:25.558
>   22303-22303/com.mnkafe.mnkafe E/MessageQueue-JNI:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   dispatchUnhandledKeyEventPre(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)Z
>   in class Landroidx/core/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat' appears in
>   /data/app/com.mnkafe.mnkafe-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1162)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2529)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2301)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4032)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3987)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3549)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3602)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3568)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3685)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3742)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3549)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3602)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3568)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3549)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3602)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3568)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3879)
>           at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2242)
>           at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1879)
>           at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1870)
>           at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2219)
>           at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5348)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742) 07-06
>   18:47:25.558 22303-22303/com.mnkafe.mnkafe D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
>   down VM 07-06 18:47:25.568 22303-22303/com.mnkafe.mnkafe
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.mnkafe.mnkafe, PID: 22303
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method dispatchUnhandledKeyEventPre(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)Z
>   in class Landroidx/core/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat' appears in
>   /data/app/com.mnkafe.mnkafe-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1162)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2529)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2301)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4032)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3987)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3549)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3602)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3568)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3685)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3742)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3549)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3602)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3568)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3576)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3549)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3602)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3568)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3879)
>           at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2242)
>           at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1879)
>           at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1870)
>           at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2219)
>           at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5348)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check you are using 1.0.0-beta01 versions everywhere (for androidx and com.google.android.... dependencies) and not 1.0.0-alpha3