# App crash when press back , volume up or down

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Im trying to update one of my Android app, i recent download and installing `android studio`, `git`, and `genymotion` to do changes..

**But im receiving this error:**

No static method dispatchUnhandledKeyEventPre(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat;

Never got it before

**Full Logcat:**

```
Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method dispatchUnhandledKeyEventPre(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/app/com.zimbronapps.barajaloteria-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1162)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2529)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3981)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2253)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1874)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1865)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2230)
    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Add the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your versions of androidx and google dependency to  1.0.0-alpha3.

Referred from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51229212/5955784)

Comment: i <3 u !  y was trying to change to beta01 but it works just now

Comment: if i upgrade graddle from 3.1 to 4 when importing project, error isnt solved